# how to let ng2-bootstrap datepicker hide

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I use ng2-bootstrap date picker ,when i click the datepicker,it still show,how to hide it?my html code is below.please help me,thank you

```html
<input type="text" [ngModel]="dt.toLocaleDateString()" (focus)="showDatePicker = true" style="width:300px;">
<div *ngIf="showDatePicker" style="position: absolute; z-index:10; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="dt"  [showWeeks]="true" ></datepicker>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. For the moment it seams to be impossible. The author is seams to be working on new version. See the repo: [HERE](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/273)

Answer (score 0):

You can use class name and id to close the datepicket popup (i.e DatePickerPopupDirective) using event target (click)="close($event.target)" and it works for me.

In My datepicker.component.html template :

```
  <div *ngIf="opened" class="dateclass">
<datepicker  [(ngModel)]="dt" [minDate]="minDate" [formatDayHeader]="E"   
    (click)="close($event.target)"
    [showWeeks]="false"></datepicker>
</div>
```

since ng2-bootstrap datepicker uses "btn btn-default btn-sm" as class name for both date and year we use id and classname in if condition.

```
public close(e:HTMLElement): void {
    if(e.className == 'btn btn-default btn-sm' && e.id !== 'undefined-title'){
    this.opened = false;
    }
}
```

My entire date picker component looks like :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES }from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-datepicker',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker.component.html',
  directives: [DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  styleUrls: ['datepicker.component.css'],
  exportAs: 'dateref'
})
export class DatepickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()  private dt: Date = new Date();
  public minDate: Date = void 0;
  public events: Array<any>;
  private opened: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.minDate = new Date();
  }
  public getDate(): any {
   return (this.dt && this.dt.getTime());
  }

  public open(): void {
    this.opened = !this.opened;
  }

  public close(e:HTMLElement): void {
    if(e.className == 'btn btn-default btn-sm' && e.id !== 'undefined-title'){
    this.opened = false;
    }
  }
 ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

In my parent template i used exportAs 'dateref' refering to @ViewChild('dp') datePicker; as:

```
<app-datepicker #dp="dateref"></app-datepicker>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my code, it works fine:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control "
           (focus)="showDatePicker = !showDatePicker" name="inputBeginDate"
           value="{{dt | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon" dropdownToggle
          (click)="showDatePicker = !showDatePicker"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    <div *ngIf="showDatePicker"
         style="position: absolute; z-index:10; min-height:290px;">
        <datepicker name="date" [showWeeks]="false" [(ngModel)]="dt" (ngModelChange)="setDate(dt);getInvoices(invoiceFilters)" (selectionDone)="showDatePicker = false"></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should, in general, try to provide an explanation on _why_ your code works and what the asker should be doing differently in order to get their own code to work instead of just providing a snippet.